# How to send byte arrays to VB6 RS-232 serial port?

Tags: bluetooth, vb6, serial-port

I have protocol document. I know VB6. But I can't send this command to RS-232 bluetooth device. I have command UINT array:

```
MyCommand = "0x8001,0x0000,0x00005358,0x0021,0x0000,0x0008,0x0001,0x0013,0x0000,0x000F,0x00FB,0x536F757263655F3000"
```

or

```
MyCommand = "0x8001 0x0000 0x00005358 0x0021 0x0000 0x0008 0x0001 0x0013 0x0000 0x000F 0x00FB 0x536F757263655F3000"

MSComm1.Output = MyCommand
```

[image: Protocol document screenshot]

Not Working !!!

Please help..

Comment: First you need a Byte array, not some String of hexish stuff.

Comment: I'd have thought you need to send each of those commands individually. Space/comma are not going to be valid terminators for serial commands.

Comment: Serial ports are not *block* devices like a card punch, so there isn't any "send individually."  You can only send a stream of data, all at once or in dribs and drabs.